# Windows randomly stop accepting input from bluetooth keyboard

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, bluetooth

I've got a laptop running Ubuntu 11.10 with the most recent updates and an Apple Wireless Keyboard that syncs via bluetooth. The Ubuntu box is also a Synergy server, using QuickSynergy to run Synergy. I'm using xmodmap to swap the option and command keys, but nothing else.

Throughout the day, windows that are long running will just stop accepting input. For example, I leave gnome-terminal up and running almost 24 hours a day. If it sits for a while, it just stops accepting input. It doesn't matter if I'm ssh'd into another machine or sitting on a local tty session, it just stops accepting input. If I open a new tab or window, those work fine. The 'broken' tabs stay broken.

I'm also running Turpial (a Twitter client) which will do that same thing. I tend to use the arrow keys to navigate, and it just stops accepting input. Closing it and reopening it causes it to work fine.

I don't seem to have the problem in Chrome, but I tend to open up new tabs when I go somewhere instead of using existing tabs.

I've updated all the packages, rebooted, and the only thing that seems to cure it is if I type on the built-in keyboard, the window will start to accept text from the bluetooth keyboard (until it stops again). I don't think the keyboard is disassociating from the laptop because it can happen while I'm using the keyboard, it seems more linked with windows that I sit for a long time. As an example, I'm typing in Chrome with the bluetooth keyboard but I have a terminal window that won't accept input.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this has nothing to do with synergys tendancy to crash frequently? When I used synergy it would crash almost daily and I had to issue another terminal command to start it up again.

Edit: Addition --

Can you check /var/log/syslog at the time the keyboard cuts out (as best as you can) for any messages that are bluetooth related or keyboard/input, or any error messages at all between when the keyboard worked and when it didn't. Copy paste any interesting or curious log messages to your original question.

Comment: Weird. I've never had synergy crash as either client or server and I've used it for years. I would get sticky keys on earlier versions of Ubuntu though. Either way, this is happening on the server, and never seems to affect the client, and I never have to restart anything.

Comment: I was using three different OSs and subsequently may have been using different versions. Regardless, its a godsend of a program, there are new versions out now that may not suffer those problems.